# how send string to COM using java app

Tags: java, string, serial-port

I'm pretty new in this and I want to send a `String` to a specific port.
I'm using jSerialComm-1.3.9 library, but I don't know how use it.

This is what I have so far:

```
public void led1() throws IOException{
    SerialPort serialPort = SerialPort.getCommPort("COM8");
    serialPort.setComPortParameters(9600,8, 1, 0);

    serialPort.setSerialPortParams(300,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
    OutputStream mOutputToPort = serialPort.getOutputStream();

    String mValue = "on";

    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(mOutputToPort);
    osw.write(mValue, 0, mValue.length());
    osw.flush();
}
```

Please help :s

Answer (score 0):

I've had very good experiences with RXTXcomm ([download link](http://www.jcontrol.org/download/rxtx_en.html)), in case you are open to changing libraries. It works both on Linux and Windows.

I'm going to share fragments of my application using this library in hope it might help you.

This is the code to open a connection:

```
private RXTXPort connect(String portName, int baud, int data, int stop, int parity) {
    RXTXPort port = null;

    try {
        CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
        port = (RXTXPort) portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(), 2000);
    } catch (NoSuchPortException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConnectionProvider.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to open connection with " + portName, ex);
    } catch(PortInUseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConnectionProvider.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to open connection with " + portName, ex);
    }

    if (port != null) {
        if (port.getBaudRate() != baud || port.getDataBits() != data || port.getStopBits() != stop || port.getParity() != parity) {
            try {
                port.setSerialPortParams(baud, data, stop, parity);
            } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ConnectionProvider.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to configure connection with " + portName, ex);
                disconnect(port);
                port = null;
            }
        }
    }

    return port;
}
```

To read from and write to the serial port:

```
RXTXPort connect = connect(null, 9600);

InputStream inputStream = connect.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

OutputStream outputStream = connect.getOutputStream();
PrintStream writer = new PrintStream(outputStream);

try {
    //Write
    String mValue = "on";                
    writer.println(mValue);

    //Read
    if (reader.ready()) {
        mValue = reader.readLine();
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {                    
    Logger.getLogger(SerialConsumer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Error accessing port with RXTX", ex);
}
```

Hope this helps. If you don't want to use RXTXComm, the overall method is the same for dealing with `InputStream` and `OutputStream`

Comment: Thanks so much! i't help me a lot. :)